# Can I add to Deezer collaborative playlist without the access token?

Tags: deezer

I want to make a small application (for personal use) that can search for and add tracks to a Deezer playlist from an offline list I have on my computer. Since I don't have a front-end in this app, I don't have an URI which I can redirect to after authentication, and therefore can't get the access token. Can I somehow add tracks to a collaborative playlist using the POST request without the permissions you have only when you (or user) log in? I made a collaborative playlist on my personal Deezer account and have the playlist id.